# How to write a function that finds the index of the greatest integer in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to write a function that will find the index of the largest number in an array, but my current function is broken by the presence of negative numbers in an array. Here is the code I have so far.

```
export let maxIndex = (a: number[]): number => {
    let biggest = -9000000000; // use to keep track of largest element
    if (a.length === 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] > biggest) {
                biggest = a[i]; 
            }
        }

    }
    return a[biggest]; 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return a[biggest];` is returning the number at the index of the *largest element found* (eg, `[0, 2, 4, 6]` will return `a[6]` which resolves to `undefined`, which doesn't make sense for what you're trying to accomplish).

You need to keep track of not only the largest number found so far, but also the *index* of that last-found largest number. Also, if you initialize the index variable to `-1`, there's no need for the initial `if` test:

```js
const maxIndex = (a) => {
    let biggestNum = -Infinity; // use to keep track of largest element
    let biggestIndex = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] > biggestNum) {
            biggestNum = a[i]; 
            biggestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return biggestIndex;
};
console.log(maxIndex([0, -1, -2]));
console.log(maxIndex([]));
console.log(maxIndex([30, 50, 40]));
```

Another method would be to spread into `Math.max`:

```js
const maxIndex = (a) => {
  const max = Math.max(...a);
  return a.indexOf(max);
};
console.log(maxIndex([0, -1, -2]));
console.log(maxIndex([]));
console.log(maxIndex([30, 50, 40]));
```